# Debugger commands are not working in perl

Tags: perl

I am learning perl debugger. I have written a code and run the debugger. To print more lines i have issued command 1  as `'DB<1> 1'` but nothing is happening. Below is the code

```
package Inventory_item;
    sub new {
    }

 package Pen;
     @ISA = (Inventory_item);

     sub new {
     }

 package Color;
     print("Executing Color statements\n");
     $colors{"blue"}  = "Die Lot 13";
     $colors{"red"}   = "Die Lot 5";

     sub new {
     }

 package main;
     print("Executing main statements\n");
```

I executed command as `'perl -d debug.txt'` . then pressing `1` as debug command but nothing happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `l` for source listing (not `1`), `c`, and `s` for stepping through code,

```
List/search source lines:               Control script execution:
  l [ln|sub]  List source code            T           Stack trace
  - or .      List previous/current line  s [expr]    Single step [in expr]
  v [line]    View around line            n [expr]    Next, steps over subs
  f filename  View source in file         <CR/Enter>  Repeat last n or s
  /pattern/ ?patt?   Search forw/backw    r           Return from subroutine
  M           Show module versions        c [ln|sub]  Continue until position
Debugger controls:                        L           List break/watch/actions
  o [...]     Set debugger options        t [expr]    Toggle trace [trace expr]
  <[<]|{[{]|>[>] [cmd] Do pre/post-prompt b [ln|event|sub] [cnd] Set breakpoint
  ! [N|pat]   Redo a previous command     B ln|*      Delete a/all breakpoints
  H [-num]    Display last num commands   a [ln] cmd  Do cmd before line
  = [a val]   Define/list an alias        A ln|*      Delete a/all actions
  h [db_cmd]  Get help on command         w expr      Add a watch expression
  h h         Complete help page          W expr|*    Delete a/all watch exprs
  |[|]db_cmd  Send output to pager        ![!] syscmd Run cmd in a subprocess
  q or ^D     Quit                        R           Attempt a restart
Data Examination:     expr     Execute perl code, also see: s,n,t expr
  x|m expr       Evals expr in list context, dumps the result or lists methods.
  p expr         Print expression (uses script's current package).
  S [[!]pat]     List subroutine names [not] matching pattern
  V [Pk [Vars]]  List Variables in Package.  Vars can be ~pattern or !pattern.
  X [Vars]       Same as "V current_package [Vars]".  i class inheritance tree.
  y [n [Vars]]   List lexicals in higher scope <n>.  Vars same as V.
  e     Display thread id     E Display all thread ids.
For more help, type h cmd_letter, or run man perldebug for all docs.
```